# Why has this question entered the Close Queue fifteen times?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I'm rather amused by the timeline of this question - [/posts/477/timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/477/timeline).
I don't think the system would flag this post 15 times, so I guess it has been sent manually to the Close Queue $≥14$ times. Yet all $15$ times thus far it has survived; what are some strong reasons to close this post/leave it open?

I recently voted to leave it open; my main thought was that it and its answers have a large number of positive votes, indicating that its something that people think is appropriate for the site.

Comment: The question, by today's standards, is quite lacking of context and effort. Of course, the question was asked on the *very first day of this website's existence*, and a long time before the deluge of questions brought up the need for better context.

Comment: @Asaf Is it possible to lock the question for historical significance? It is currently closed. This would preserve the content, whilst suggesting that the question doesn't abide by current standards.

Comment: Actually, I've edited the question to improve it, based on one of the questions which was merged with it. Also, the comments below the question make slightly more sense now. (I would be grateful if someone could double-check my edits though :-) )

Comment: Here is a SEDE query to find [posts with many close votes reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1252613/posts-with-most-reviews-of-a-specific-type?type=2). (And by changing the type parameter, you can find posts which had many review of other types.)

Comment: Not this question, but some others like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/511904/timeline) have been used as review audit multiple times.

Comment: +1 and nice to know the birthday of Math.SE

Comment: Asked on $22^{nd}$ July, that's an alternate version of $\pi$ day :)

Comment: People is voting to close a 10 year old question? Damn, someone needs to find a hobby of something.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu That's Tau day!

Comment: @SujalMotagi Didn't know it existed, but Googled it to find out that it's celebrated on $28^{th}$ June, rather than $22^{nd}$ July. By the way, are you referring $\tau = 2\pi$ in this context?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu, Oh yeah Tau=6.28... a silly calculation mistake. And I didn't know that Tau day existed, I just made it up :p.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu, why is 22nd July, an alternate version of Pi day.

Comment: @SujalMotagi : $\pi\approx22/7$.

Comment: @SujalMotagi The actual $\pi$ day is celebrated on $14^{th}$ March, at $1:59:26$, as they are the first few digits of $\pi$ : $3.1415926...$

Comment: The post gets into the close vote queue roughly every months, looks someone bookmarked the question and vote to close whenever the option is available.

Comment: If someone is indeed voting to close repeatedly as @ArcticChar suggests, I think some moderator action would be worthwhile here. That is just creating annoyance for a lot of people just because someone is angry about some perceived slight of this post's existence.

Comment: @cameron but it seems that it is not against the rules to vote to close the same post multiple times, so i think the mods would not take any action.  Also, one consequence of this action is that others user' time are wasted in reviewing. But besides that i dont see any big problem. Their close votes would be effective only once anyway.

Comment: The point i want to make is that if it is clear that the community holds a different point of view, then one should do something else, says improving the post. Closing is not the only options.